# Frequently disconnect the mssql server and getting errors like "core dumped" and sometime "memory corruption"

Tags: sql-server, django, amazon-web-services, pyodbc, freetds

I'm using python3.5.2, django==1.11, ubuntu16.04, AWS RDS, MSSQL
server 17, UNIXODBC==3.2.1, FREETDS (freetds v0.91, TDS version: 4.2)

In my django settings:

```
   os.environ['TDSVER'] = '8.0'

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'HOST': 'host_name',
            'PORT': '1433',
            'NAME': 'test',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': 'test',
            'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'host_is_server': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /dashboard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 202, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 309, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 207, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 35, in load
    expire_date__gt=timezone.now()

  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 309, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
*** Error in `/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x00007fad5807d130 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fad780ab7e5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so(+0x3bf39)[0x7fad6ca2ff39]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2(SQLDriverConnectW+0x98c)[0x7fad71b850ec]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_Z14Connection_NewP7_objectbblbS0_R6Object+0x2c3)[0x7fad71dcac53]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x13d8e)[0x7fad71dd4d8e]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python(PyCFunction_Call+0x77)[0x4e9ba7]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python[0x4ebd98]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x47)[0x5c1797]
======= Memory map:=======
00000-007a00 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4587                            
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python3.5
009a9000-009ab000 r--p 003a9000 08:01 45878                                                     
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/bin/python3.5
00000-0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/speedups/_speedups.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/shapely/.libs/libgeos_c-bd8d3f16.so.1.10.               /home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so    
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/.libs_cffi_backend/libffi-ae16d830.so.6.0.4
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.abi3.so
7fad6930c000-7fad694cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
/home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/.libs/libfreetype-c8a1f873.so.6.14.0                /home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fad699bc000-7fad69bbc000 ---p 00004000 08:01 4858292                                       /home/qmcpl/projects/eddie/env_newmodel/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.soAborted (core dumped)
```

Note:

The server was working fine and no issue on AWS RDS instance where the
MSSQL server is there. We are the three user(dev), max to max 30-40
connections may be there in AWS RDS settings. Facing frequently this
error sometime, sometime within 2-5 hours, sometime within 10 min, and
sometime we don't get the error in 6 to 8 hours.

I have checked the /etc/odbcinst.ini file:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] 
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.4.0
UsageCount=1

[FreeTDS] 
Description=FreeTDS Driver 
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] 
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

> Sometime I also get below error:

```
python: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Several of the items in your stack are quite old, especially unixODBC 2.3.1 (released almost 7 years ago) and FreeTDS 0.91 (released at least 3 years ago). You might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: Since you have the `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, I'd recommend using it. Which Django package are you using, `django-pyodbc-azure`? See STEP 4 here: https://pyphilly.org/django-and-sql-server-2018-edition/